# Excel VBA Vlookup taking huge time

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to reduce the time that a vlookup takes in vba? I am simply using the `.range.formula` and `vlookup` formula for it ..it is taking huge time and getting hung.

```
Range("BO2:BO" & NewLastRow).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(BN2,'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!$BL$2:$BM$" & OldLastRow & ",2,0)"
```

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: .Range("BO2:BO" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(BN2,'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!$BL$2:$BM$" & OldLastRow & ",2,0)"

Comment: I have more than 300k rows of data for vlookup.

Comment: More code, *added to your question* (not in a comment) would be useful.  What are typical values for NewLastRow, OldLastRow ?

Comment: Around 300K in each sheet

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656808/how-to-optimize-vlookup-for-high-search-count-alternatives-to-vlookup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to optimize vlookup for high search count ? (alternatives to VLOOKUP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656808/how-to-optimize-vlookup-for-high-search-count-alternatives-to-vlookup)