# Avoid the "#value" error when using a Vlookup with Scrypting Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, vlookup

I am trying to use a VBA Vlookup that I found in the Question below but I keep getting the result #Value (and I am not the only one according to the comments).
Question: [How to optimize vlookup for high search count ? (alternatives to VLOOKUP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656808/how-to-optimize-vlookup-for-high-search-count-alternatives-to-vlookup)

[image]

After putting the Function in VBA. I am using it in my sheet like a normal Vlookup: "`=vbalookup(value,Range,Col)`". 
I also tried as an array formula but it still doesn't work.

Does someone see why?

```
Function vbalookup(lookupRange As Range, refRange As Range, dataCol As Long) As Variant
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim myRow As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim vResults() As Variant

    ' 1. Build a dictionnary
    For Each myRow In refRange.Columns(1).Cells
        ' Append A : B to dictionnary
        dict.Add myRow.Value, myRow.Offset(0, dataCol - 1).Value
    Next myRow

    ' 2. Use it over all lookup data
    ReDim vResults(1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count, 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count) As Variant
    For I = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For J = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
          If dict.Exists(lookupRange.Cells(I, J).Value) Then
            vResults(I, J) = dict(lookupRange.Cells(I, J).Value)
          End If
        Next J
    Next I

    vbalookup = vResults
End Function
```

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.  I suspect this solution isn't actually what you're looking for, and if we have sample data we can probably come up with something more suited to your needs.

Comment: Do you have a reference set to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library?

Comment: @Rory Yes I have

Comment: @tigeravatar I will edit my post with a sample soon then. I thought I don t need a sample as it could be used as a normal vlookup as well, was I wrong?

Comment: Are all the values in the lookup column unique?

Comment: Yes also, I have just updated a small picture to show the error

Comment: Since `vbalookup` returns an Array, on the worksheet you need to enter as an array formula `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`.

Comment: @xidgel it is entered as an Array already (see picture)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of blindly copying code from someone else, I highly suggest first learning what the code is doing. If you must blindly copy, read the comments first: [How to optimize vlookup for high search count ? (alternatives to VLOOKUP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656808/how-to-optimize-vlookup-for-high-search-count-alternatives-to-vlookup#comment42059803_18656809)

Taking a stab at the problem with the code (beyond issues with design, syntax, indentation, etc) is that your function isn't returning a specific value:

```
    ReDim vResults(1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count, 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count) As Variant
    For I = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For J = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
          If dict.Exists(lookupRange.Cells(I, J).Value) Then
            vResults(I, J) = dict(lookupRange.Cells(I, J).Value)
          End If
        Next J
    Next I

    vbalookup = vResults
```

Do you see how it is creating a 2d array, and returns this array as a result of the formula? Try adding a breakpoint before the end of the function, and take a look at what `vResults` is in the `Locals` window.

This means that, in order to actually use the function, it **must** be entered in the cell as an array formula.

To do this simply, press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of `ENTER` when entering the formula into the cell.

This comes with a strong caution though: not only do you already not know how this code is working, but you also likely don't know how array formulas work. **You, and you alone are responsible for your calculations**. If you are working on anything important whatsoever, then **here be dragons** and turn the other way.

Once you get to the point of understanding how this all works, you may have an easier time using the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right that I haven t understood totally the Function. Please check my edit on my question as it didn t work already as an array either (now I understand why it has to be an array though)

Comment: @Pierre44 Then let me re-emphasize. **HERE BE DRAGONS**. Not a good idea to move forward if you can't understand the code.