# Huge spreadhseet - slow calculation speed for formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with about 300,000 records. I am applying a Vlookup formula on the first row and then trying to copy and paste special as formulas to the remaining rows. But, the calculation tends to consume a lot of time and shows progress in multi-threads which is really slow.

Could someone suggest a way to do this to save some time.

Thank you!

Comment: "Could someone suggest a way to do this to save some time" -- use a database. Excel isn't a database, so why use it as one?

Comment: I completely agree with that. But, this was one of the situations I got stuck into. So, I just wanted to know if there's any way. Just curious.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656809/4996248) might help. You could also think about turning your records into a pivot table (if they aren't one already) which is the closest Excel comes to emulating a database.

Comment: Are you any array formula in your sheet? Array formula causes excel slow down. Can you show us your sample data and formulas you are using, then we may some suggestion for you.

Comment: If your vlookup is over mulitple columns of data, try instead using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` and reference only the columns you need to assess and return... Try to avoid volatile formulas like `INDIRECT()` if at all possible or use manual calculation if you have them in there (can then hit F9 or click calculate now to calculate on demand). Have a quick search online, there are plenty of examples of using these or alternatives for them. If you have static data being calculated by a formula (data that will never change) copy it and paste values as there is no need for these to re-calculate.

Comment: If you're returning multiple values from the same `lookup_value` in VLOOKUP it will be faster to use a single match to find the correct row and multiple `INDEX` to return the values.  I don't usually post links to outside sites unless they're MSDN sites but [Decision Models - optimising lookups](http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeede.htm) does have some good pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to do an exact match lookup then the fastest formula way to do this is to sort your data and then use the double VLOOKUP trick.

see my blog post for details:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/

Comment: Damn, you're just just getting yourself out there Charles.  Already linked to your website on my last comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with it, your best bet is to optimize your formulas by avoiding common pitfalls. You've mentioned that you're using `VLOOKUP`, why not try `INDEX/MATCH` combo, it is more versatile and is faster than `VLOOKUP`. Other optimizing techniques include:

- avoiding volatile formulas
- using helper columns
- arrange the columns in such a way that the sequence of your calculation is from left to right, top to bottom, very much like reading English text
- Use structured and named references
- Enable manual calculation so that formulas are not recalculated every time you make even the slightest change

You may also want to use a timer to measure Excel calculation time, for you to compare your different approaches, such as this one by Charles Williams, from an article in Microsoft Developer Network. Paste this code into the VBA editor:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" Alias _
        "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias _
         "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" Alias _                                            "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
    Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias _
        "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long
#End If
Function MicroTimer() As Double
'

' Returns seconds.
    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency
    '
    MicroTimer = 0

' Get frequency.
    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency

' Get ticks.
    getTickCount cyTicks1                            

' Seconds
    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency 
End Function

Sub RangeTimer()
    DoCalcTimer 1
End Sub
Sub SheetTimer()
    DoCalcTimer 2
End Sub
Sub RecalcTimer()
    DoCalcTimer 3
End Sub
Sub FullcalcTimer()
    DoCalcTimer 4
End Sub

Sub DoCalcTimer(jMethod As Long)
    Dim dTime As Double
    Dim dOvhd As Double
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oArrRange As Range
    Dim sCalcType As String
    Dim lCalcSave As Long
    Dim bIterSave As Boolean
    '
    On Error GoTo Errhandl

' Initialize
    dTime = MicroTimer              

    ' Save calculation settings.
    lCalcSave = Application.Calculation
    bIterSave = Application.Iteration
    If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End If
    Select Case jMethod
    Case 1

        ' Switch off iteration.

        If Application.Iteration <> False Then
            Application.Iteration = False
        End if

        ' Max is used range.

        If Selection.Count > 1000 Then
            Set oRng = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)
        Else
            Set oRng = Selection
        End If

        ' Include array cells outside selection.

        For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.HasArray Then
                If oArrRange Is Nothing Then 
                    Set oArrRange = oCell.CurrentArray
                End If
                If Intersect(oCell, oArrRange) Is Nothing Then
                    Set oArrRange = oCell.CurrentArray
                    Set oRng = Union(oRng, oArrRange)
                End If
            End If
        Next oCell

        sCalcType = "Calculate " & CStr(oRng.Count) & _
            " Cell(s) in Selected Range: "
    Case 2
        sCalcType = "Recalculate Sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & ": "
    Case 3
        sCalcType = "Recalculate open workbooks: "
    Case 4
        sCalcType = "Full Calculate open workbooks: "
    End Select

' Get start time.
    dTime = MicroTimer
    Select Case jMethod
    Case 1
        If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
            oRng.CalculateRowMajorOrder
        Else
            oRng.Calculate
        End If
    Case 2
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Case 3
        Application.Calculate
    Case 4
        Application.CalculateFull
    End Select

' Calculate duration.
    dTime = MicroTimer - dTime
    On Error GoTo 0

    dTime = Round(dTime, 5)
    MsgBox sCalcType & " " & CStr(dTime) & " Seconds", _
        vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "CalcTimer"

Finish:

    ' Restore calculation settings.
    If Application.Calculation <> lCalcSave Then
         Application.Calculation = lCalcSave
    End If
    If Application.Iteration <> bIterSave Then
         Application.Iteration = bIterSave
    End If
    Exit Sub
Errhandl:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "Unable to Calculate " & sCalcType, _
        vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "CalcTimer"
    GoTo Finish
End Sub
```

You may also check the links under References for more suggestions and techniques in optimizing Excel performance. Although in the second link, it said:

*"It is usually faster to use the Excel formula calculations and worksheet functions than to use VBA user-defined functions."*[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions)

Although this may be true if we're talking about the process of calculation itself but if you do your calculations in VBA, your output will be static. So if you're doing let's say financial modelling, what-if scenarios, and such, it'll be painful to wait for 15 minutes for each minute changes if automatic calculation is enabled because the formulas are actively referencing the cells, monitoring for any changes.

Hope this helps..

---

References:

[Excel performance: Improving calculation performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-improving-calcuation-performance)

[Excel performance: Tips for optimizing performance obstructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions)

[Excel performance: Performance and limit improvements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements)